# iOS charts will not draw multiple datasets when the sets use different ranges of X-coordinates

Tags: ios-charts

When creating a line chart from more than one data sets, the line chart only shows one of the data sets and when zooming or panning the chart it crashes with *Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound*.

If I create the line chart from one data set it works as expected.

This problem only occurs when the two datasets have completely different ranges of X values.

The code below should draw a chart with x ranging from 0 to 19 (i.e. 2 datasets). But it only draws the second dataset. The chart crashes if you pan or zoom it.

If I edit the code, replacing `for x in (10..<20)` with `for x in (0..<10)`, both datasets are correctly drawn and the chart does not crash.

To summarise: when adding two dataSets that have entries with different ranges of X coordinates the chart draws incorrectly and will crash.

Is there an iOS_charts API call needed to prevent this? How can I draw two datasets that do not have overlapping X-coordinates?

I've been able to produce the same crash when running code using [this demo code](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Swift/Demos/MultipleLinesChartViewController.swift) if I modify it to create multiple datasets that have non-overlapping x-coordinates.

```
class ElevationChartViewController: UIViewController {
   
    @IBOutlet var chartView: LineChartView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        chartView.backgroundColor = .white
        chartView.legend.enabled = false
        chartView.maxVisibleCount = 20000
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let dataSets = createChartDataSets()
        chartView.data = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    }
}

func createChartDataSets() -> [LineChartDataSet] {
      var dataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()
      var entriesOne = [ChartDataEntry]()
      var entriesTwo = [ChartDataEntry]()
      var y = 0.0
      for x in (0..<10) {
          entriesOne.append( ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y))
          y = y + 10
          if y > 60 {y = 0.0}
      }
      dataSets.append(LineChartDataSet(entriesOne))
      
      for x in (10..<20) {
          entriesTwo.append( ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y))
          y = y + 10
          if y > 50 {y = 0.0}
      }
      dataSets.append(LineChartDataSet(entriesTwo))

      return dataSets
}
```

Swift version: 5.4
Xcode 12.4
Observed running on a real iPhone 12 sw version 14.4
Charts v4.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been facing a similar issue and this solution worked for me so far. Not sure about potential side effects that could arise from this. I have not tested with panning or zooming.

Subclass `LineChartDataSet` and override `entryIndex(x xValue:closestToY  yValue:rounding)` copy and paste the super implementation, but remove the `guard` statement at the top of the function

```
    var closest = partitioningIndex { $0.x >= xValue }
    guard closest < endIndex else { return -1 }
```

and replace with

```
    var closest = partitioningIndex { $0.x >= xValue }
    if closest >= endIndex {
      closest = endIndex - 1
    }
```

Comment: This works for me. And it works for panning and zooming. I'll accept it as an answer even though I acknowledge it could be poor solution in the long run and is a hack of the library. I'll report this "workaround" on the iOS Charts GitHub page. I'm also unsure about side effects. Thanks very, very much Marrrrk!

Comment: when `endIndex` is 0, this solution ends up with a crash caused by
`self[closest].x -> self[-1].x`

Comment: Solved my issue as well! Thanks a lot! ‍♂️

Comment: Note that when copying the `entryIndex()` function implementation, it has to be copied from `ChartDataSet`, not 'LineChartDataSet` (where it is not implemented/overridden).

Comment: This resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Tag 5.0.0 of Charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) does not have the problem that version 4.1.0 had, as described in this issue.